# Is there a better way to force a bit of whitespace on the last line of a paragraph?

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, paragraphs

I'm new to latex (XeTeX). My justified, 5-mm indented text is long; and at several places, the last line of a paragraph flushes completely right—creating possible irritation for the reader. To fix this, I've inserted

```
\def\RemoveSpaces#1{%
  \begingroup
  \spaceskip100000sp
  \xspaceskip100000sp
  #1%
  \endgroup}
```

in the preamble and, in the text, have selected out for whitespace-removal (between words) only the offending last lines. This seems to work. (A test-reader couldn't tell that the offending lines were slightly smushed.)

But is there a better way, typographically, to create such whitespace at the end of the last line of a paragraph? I've tried `\hspace` with a custom value, `\hspace*` with a custom value, and `\parfillskip`, but none of these seem to work, even though the documentation for `\parskip` seems to have a note on how to use `\parfillskip` to fix this problem:

"With package option `parfill`, the package also adjusts `\parfillskip` to impose a minimum space at the end of the last line of a paragraph. If specified without a value then 30pt are assumed, if a value is given that forms the minimum."

I've also come across this comment that touches on my problem exactly:

[image]

But that code doesn't seem to work.

Minimal example (using David Carlisle's):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two threee four five six seven
one two three four five. <- is the offending flush line I need pushed back.]

one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two threee four five six seven
one two three four five.

\end{document}
```

My solution has been the following:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\def\RemoveSpaces#1{%
  \begingroup
  \spaceskip100000sp
  \xspaceskip100000sp
  #1%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two threee four five six seven
\RemoveSpaces{one two three four five.}

one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two threee four five six seven
one two three four five.

\end{document}
```

My solution works: it removes interword spacing from only the specific offending line, thereby creating some whitespace directly after (not below) it. But is there a better way, typographically, to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: changing spaceskip in that way will break justification completely, you need the interword space to stretch or shrink to justify each line but you are setting it to a fixed length (in sp units !) it may accidentally affect the space at the end of the paragraph but mostly because it affects all space between all words.  \parfillskip is the space on the last line and you want to set it to a value that can not shrink to zero.

Comment: I guess you want `\setlength{\parfillskip}{10pt plus 1fil}` and that the `@` characters were the problem.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. This solution creates a problem, though: it doesn't give me whitespace directly at the end of the offending line but rather shoves the last word to a new line, creating an even uglier situation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. But when I've set off the specific offending line with \RemoveSpaces{} the rest of the text is unaffected (seemingly).

Comment: @Lijishe yes if you add it manually after linebreaking I assumed you were adding it to the original source, but even so there is no reason to suppose that that word spacing produces a reasonable end of paragraph space. conversely you can set `\parfillskip` globally in advance to specify the minimum end of paragraph space

Comment: @Lijishe I'm not sure what you mean. Anyway, if you want to ensure some nonzero white space at the end of a paragraph, you have to live with the last word going to the next line, which of course might as well happen with the standard setting, so I don't really see a problem. When your text is in final form, you can look at bad line breaks which might be solved by rewording or by adding ties. Doing such optimizations during the writing stage is a waste of time.

Comment: @egreg But do you really have to live with it? For example, in my case, the solution I'm using--i.e., \RemoveSpaces{The king is dead.}--doesn't push the last word to a new line; my solution imperceptibly crunches up the offending sentence and creates a tiny bit of whitespace at the end of it. I'm happy with this solution. I'm just wondering whether there is a better typographical solution than either mine or "living with the last word going to the next line."

Comment: @Lijishe Any method can be used; but, trust me, think to this only when the text is in final form.

Answer (score 4):

The space at the end of the paragraph is `\parfillskip` if you set this to a length that is (say) 10mm minimum, but stretching as large as possible then at least 10mm will be kept on the last line, either by shrinking the space on that line, or by taking some text over to thenext line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two threee four five six seven
one two three four five.


\setlength\parfillskip{10mm plus 1fill}

one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two three four five six seven
one two threee four five six seven
one two three four five.

\end{document}
```